# Functional programming, objects that act as functions but don't return a value

Tags: java, functional-programming

I am trying to do some functional programming with java.

`Function` Objects takes one value and returns one value. `Method` takes no arguments.

Is there a default Object which takes one argument and returns nothings? Or should I create my own?

```
NewObject<String> stopListAdd =
            line -> stopList.add(xxx);
```

If I were to construct my own is there any way better than extending the Function object and just dismissing its return value?

Comment: What you're looking for is called a [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html).

Comment: Or, if it doesn't have an argument, a `Runnable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, java uses functional interfaces to back the type behind lambdas. In short, when creating a lambda you are just implementing an interface with a single abstract method, called a functional interface. So if you want to create your functional types, you just need to create an interface with a single abstract method that matches your requirements, like in this case

```
void accept();
```

One side note, default methods can be added to a functional interface as they are in fact implemented already.

So, Function and other similar types are not the full extents of functional types in java, but rather a subset of commonly used, reusable and well-known functional interfaces that you don't have to redeclare each and every time.

Comment: I think `accept` would have an argument, no?  Otherwise it's just a `Runnable`.

Comment: Not necessarily, nothing stops you from creating your own functional interface even when something with the same signature already exists. You could use Runnable, for sure, as it matches the definition of functional interface or you can create your own functional interface, the choice is yours.

Answer (score 2):

[`java.util.function.Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html) accepts a single input argument and returns no result.